# how to create a processor in nifi from command line terminal ubuntu?

Tags: rest, curl, apache-nifi

I am trying to create a processor using below command from command line interface ubuntu.

```
curl -i -k  -X POST https://localhost:8443/nifi-api/process-groups/ad20fee5-017e-1000-9155-7e71f5041700 -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d '{"revision":{"version":0},"disconnectedNodeAcknowledged":false,"component":{"type":"org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GetSFTP","bundle":{"group":"org.apache.nifi","artifact":"nifi-standard-nar","version":"1.15.3"},"name":"GetSFTP","position":{"x":249,"y":-350.5}}},'
```

I am getting the following error

HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Date: Thu, 28 Jul 2022 11:45:22 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31540000
Set-Cookie: __Secure-Request-Token=d0616785-6dbf-479e-9576-a27ddd44a0f9; Path=/; Secure
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 27
Server: Jetty(9.4.44.v20210927)

Comment: Check https://github.com/InsightByte/ApacheNifi/tree/main/Chapter-13

Comment: there is no endpoint for `POST /process-groups/{id}` https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html